# How do I run a program with a user created package in java using command prompt

Tags: java, package

**Java program**
It contains a user created package and has four class including one main class
How can I run this code in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a executable jar file.
Create a top empty directory, create a folder inside with the name of your package, copy the compiled classes inside.From top directory execute ( With proper class names)

```
    jar cvfe myJarFile.jar package.MyMainClass package/*.class
```

And to run the jar file

```
java -jar myJarFile.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

At the root directory of the project, you can do

```
javac package/*.java
```

(you may replace / with \ on Windows)

and then

```
java package.MainClass
```